# How to parse json feed in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, object, dictionary

How can I parse json feed in c#?

I tried following so far:

```
         string fileurl = "http://itunes.apple.com/rss/customerreviews/id=123456789/json";

        var jsonStr = new WebClient().DownloadString(fileurl);

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var jsonObject = serializer.Deserialize<IDictionary<string, object>>(jsonStr);
```

Once i get `Dictionary<string, object> dic1 = new Dictionary<string, object>();` using above code.

i iterate to get the `value object[]` as shown below.

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, object> d in dic1)
        {
            var k = d.Key;
            var v = d.Value;
         }
```

Now the `value` is `System.Object[]` type so can anyone help me parse this object as shown in the below image? I'm new to this so any help would be great!

[image]

Comment: Try another for each statement within your foreach?

Comment: can you give example because i tried and getting an Error: "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator"

Comment: There are implementations of JSON parsing in C# that already exist.  Json.NET (http://json.codeplex.com/) is one.  It gives you nice Linq support as well, so you can easily query the data, etc.

Comment: I can not convert it to object as the json feed has some illegal character such as 'im:version' as you see in the image of my question so I have to convert it to Dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use JSON.NET in situations like this.  There is an example here where he parses a rss feed using LINQ,

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/

There is also the SelectToken method which queries the parsed JSON using a path syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You're deserializing to the wrong type.

In your code,

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonObject = serializer.Deserialize<IDictionary<string, object>>(jsonStr);
```

you specify that it needs to deserialize to type `IDictionary<string, object>`. Try matching the type to something other than `object`.

Comment: i specified IDictionary<string, object> because object is unknown and I can not convert it to object as the json feed has some illegal character such as 'im:version'

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the ServiceStack's JSON parser will help - it supports [dynamic JSON](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#supports-dynamic-json-as-well).